# How to create Bootstrap Multi level signup page in angular 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm using angular 4 with bootstrap 4. I need to create a multi-level sign-up page. Now I'm facing issue to include the JavaScript file into angular.

```
import  '../../../assets/js/js/multiform.js'
```

used this to import the file into my @Component ;

I need to call a function when the user click "NEXT / BACK"; But my function not calling

Answer (score 0):

Forget about importing pure javascript plugins. It's not a good practice in Angular 2+. You can create your own component for it, or use the open source examples that are already angularized. I think something like this is what you are looking for: https://github.com/cwun/angular-multi-step-wizard.
Good luck.